# Powershell rename with variable and special characters

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, rename

I’m trying to rename some files. In the path and filename there are symbols like `[`, `]` and spaces.
The rename command says it can´t find the file.

There is a main file with the symbols and a "temp" file. The main file should be deleted and the name of the temp file should be from the original.

my code is:

```
$onlypath = Split-Path -Path $_.FullName
Rename-Item $onlypath + "\TEMP" $_.Name
```

and testet many other syntax like

```
Rename-Item -Path "$onlypath\TEMP" -NewName $_.Name 
or
Rename-Item -Path $onlypath"\TEMP" -NewName $_.Name 
or
Rename-Item -Path $onlypath + "\TEMP" -NewName $_.Name
```

the error is everytime, that the file is not at this place.
i tried the command in a shell and the same error but if i add ` as escape char before the symbols it works.

greetings

Comment: What problems are you having with this code?

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong. Please read about [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.3) before asking a question.

Comment: i read this and i tried diffrent types of syntax. (i updated the question). every time the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you do not want to rename the file, but **Move** it to a new path.
Rename-Item is for well.. renaming a file where it actually is located. You then give it a new file name, it is not for changing the path.

Also, if the file has symbols like `[,]`, you need to specify `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`

Try

```
$sourcePath  = 'X:\Somewhere\Here[123]'
$destination = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath 'Temp'
# make sure the destination folder exists
$null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
# get the files and move them to the destination
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourcePath -File | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $destination
}
```

Comment: thanks! i switched to move with -force. and the -LiteralPath fixed it :-)

Comment: @Err0r Sorry, forgot to add `-Force` to the New-Item cmdlet. Added it now